# How to get the coordinates of the closest point along a line?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, distance

I have a plot as below (the plot is just for illustration purpose. in my real problem, I just have `pts1`):-

```
pts1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[7]; RandomReal[2.9, {30, 2}]];
pts1L = MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2] &, {pts1, Range[Length@pts1]}];
plot1 = ListPlot[pts1L, PlotRange -> {{0, 3.5}, {0, 3}}];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[{3, t}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Darker[Red]];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

When I have a vector representing the red line, let say `redLine = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}`, I want to have the coordinates of the closet points as output, i.e. `{pts1[[17]], pts1[[17]], pts1[[22]], pts1[[9]], pts1[[26]], 
 pts1[[13]], pts1[[6]]}` as output.

My current solution is as below, but that's too clumsy and will be very slow when the scale of the problem increase. What are the more efficient ways to get it done? (For example, is it possible to calculate the `DistanceMatrix` of just "frontline points v.s. red line" instead of "all points v.s. red line"?)

```
redLine = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}
redLineCood = Transpose@ArrayFlatten[{ConstantArray[3, Length@redLine], redLine}]
dM = DistanceMatrix[redLineCood, pts1];
min = Min /@ dM;
pts1[[Flatten@MapThread[Position[#1, #2] &, {dM, min}]]]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: pts1=BlockRandom[SeedRandom[7];RandomReal[2.9,{30,2}]];
redLine={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3}; redLineCood=Map[{3,#}&,redLine];
f[p_]:=MinimalBy[pts1,Norm[p-#]&][[1]];
f/@redLineCood

Comment: Thanks. This is so elegant.

Comment: If the shortest possible distance from pi to the red line is greater than the greatest possible distance from pj to the red line then pi could be discarded. But that is still roughly an n^2 process of comparing all pi against all pj. I don't see any way of overcoming that. Ah, and `redLineCood={3,#}&/@redLine;`

Comment: ‘Nearest[pts, #, 1]& /@ Thread[{3, redLine}]’?

Comment: Thanks, `Nearest[pts1] /@ Thread[{3, redLine}]` works so well!

Comment: Are you looking for the points closest to the line or for the points closes to the pointcloud that defines this line? These are different things.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Hi, I am looking for "points closes to the pointcloud that defines this line". Do you mean when I change `redLine` from `{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}` to `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, I would miss out `pts1[[13]]` since it is with respect to `2.5`?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Nearest[pts1] /@ Thread[{3, redLine}]
```